# How can I fetch a hierarchical tree structure in Diesel?

Tags: sql, rust, rust-diesel

I want to create a SQL database using Diesel. One of the tables will contain something called `groups` which can be thought of as a hierarchical  tree structure: a group can be root group, or it can have a single parent. Each group should have a `unique_id` and a user who owns it and a potential parent.

How do I create this struct such that Diesel would be able to fetch the whole tree below a given group? If that is possible, how would I execute it?

I'm quite new to web development, so I'm not too well acquainted with how to achieve what I want.

Comment: You appear to be trying to learn multiple separate things concurrently; I'd recommend trying to learn them separately to start with. Modeling tree-like structures in SQL has multiple implementations, and they all have benefits and downsides. There's even entire *graph databases* because the problem can be difficult! Once you have figured out your data organization, then you can deal with creating the SQL query required to get what you want. Once you have that, you can then figure out how to get Diesel to do what you want. You will also have to figure out how to represent the tree in Rust!

Comment: Could you point me to any information on how to do this in SQL. I know there and graph databases, but for now I would like to do it in SQL as there is other logic which resides in SQL.